# how to enable "what I follow" in lightning community

Tags: lightning-community, community-builder

I was trying to migrate the salesforce classic community to lightning. There is a chatter feed in our classic community where it shows all the posts related to groups that the user follows ("What I follow" in profile). But I am not able to find this option in experience builder or via apex using 'chatter:newsfeed' in lightning community to replicate the same. In lightning community it is only showing the posts where the user is tagged which is similar to 'To me' in classic community. Were anyone able to find a workaround / is there an existing solution to this?